# Is it possible to have a static constexpr member with type X of template class X?

Tags: c++, templates, static, constexpr

I once had 4 classes for 4 different RGB implementations (rgb, rgba, rgbf32, rgbaf32).
Each class had a member color, and the code worked perfectly fine:

```
struct rgb {
    std::uint8_t r;
    std::uint8_t g;
    std::uint8_t b;

    const static rgb red;
};
constexpr rgb rgb::red = rgb{ 255, 0, 0 };

int main() {
    constexpr auto red = rgb::red;
}
```

I had 4 times the code length because of this, so I decided to combine them into one templated class:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>

template<bool f32, bool alpha>
using rgb_content =
    std::conditional_t<(!f32 && !alpha), std::array<std::uint8_t, 3>,
    std::conditional_t<(!f32 &&  alpha), std::array<std::uint8_t, 4>,
    std::conditional_t<( f32 && !alpha), std::array<float, 3>,
                                         std::array<float, 4>>>>;

template<bool f32, bool alpha>
struct rgb {
    rgb_content<f32, alpha> color;

    constexpr static auto get_red() {
        return rgb { f32 ? 1 : 255, 0, 0 };
    }

    const static rgb<f32, alpha> red;
};

template<bool f32, bool alpha>
const rgb<f32, alpha> rgb<f32, alpha>::red = rgb<f32, alpha>::get_red();

int main() {
    constexpr auto red = rgb<0, 0>::red;
}
```

I no longer get the static member `red` to work with this template class ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xeehzfaq4)):

```
error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
```

---

I tried switching around `constexpr` and other keywords, but no success. The only solution I found was naming all possibilities:

```cpp
constexpr rgb<0, 0> rgb<0, 0>::red = rgb<0, 0>::get_red();
constexpr rgb<0, 1> rgb<0, 1>::red = rgb<0, 1>::get_red();
constexpr rgb<1, 0> rgb<1, 0>::red = rgb<1, 0>::get_red();
constexpr rgb<1, 1> rgb<1, 1>::red = rgb<1, 1>::get_red();

int main() {
    using u8 = std::uint8_t;

    static_assert(rgb<0, 0>::red.color == std::array{(u8)255u, (u8)0u, (u8)0u});
    static_assert(rgb<0, 1>::red.color == std::array{(u8)255u, (u8)0u, (u8)0u, (u8)0u});
    static_assert(rgb<1, 0>::red.color == std::array{1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f});
    static_assert(rgb<1, 1>::red.color == std::array{1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f});
}
```

but this only compiles with MSVC (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/YcxWdYqPE)) and it's pretty unmaintanable.

---

Is this even possible to implement? Do I have to use `constexpr static` member functions like `red()` instead?

Comment: Side note, your `rgb_content` can be `template<bool f32, bool alpha> using rgb_content = std::array<std::conditional_t<f32, float, std::uint8_t>, alpha ? 4 : 3>;`

Answer (score 2):

```
constexpr auto red = rgb<0, 0>::red;
```

`rgb<0,0>::red` is not a `constexpr` value, this doesn't work.

This compiles for me, with gcc 12:

```
template<bool f32, bool alpha>
struct rgb {
    rgb_content<f32, alpha> color;

    constexpr static auto get_red() {
        return rgb { f32 ? 1 : 255, 0, 0 };
    }

    constexpr static rgb<f32, alpha> red=get_red();
};
```

Comment: Well, it seems like only gcc will compile this: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8rvvrnM8P).

Comment: Irrespective of any particular compiler's hangups, you can only use a `constexpr` to set another `constexpr`; so one way or another the `red` has to be a `constexpr`.

Comment: in the very first example, the `static const` version compiled for all 3 version [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9z7hMj87b). but when I make it `constexpr` it no longer works on any version. (it gives `use of undefined type rgb` [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vdcYKKsTT))